# Program.Mattor(): not all code paths return a value. How do I solve this?

Tags: c#, methods, return

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /// </summary>
        /// Tapet:

        // Följande ska användaren kunna mata in:
        // 1. Väggens mått: Längd och bredd.
        // 2. Jämförelse av upp till 8 st tapeter.

        // Programmet ska även kunna skriva ut en lista av alla tapet där man tydligt ser namn, antal rullar och pris. 

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        ///Mattor:

        // Användaren ska kunna mata in golvets bredd och längd.

        // Användaren ska sedan kunna mata in olika areor på mattor tills det täcker golvets yta.  

        // Vi ska bestämma när antalet mattor har täckt golvet, samt hur många mattor det tog.

        //.......

        // Variabeln menyKörs sätts till true så vi kan skapa en While-loop som hela tiden körs om. Detta avbryter vi genom att sätta den till
        // false ifall användaren väljer att avsluta programmet. 
        bool menyKörs = true;
        while (menyKörs)
        {
            //Ett programm som hjälper anändaren att tappetsera en vägg eller lägga mattor på användarens golv

            Console.WriteLine("Hej! Välkommen till programmet som hjälper dig med att tappetsera och lägga golvmattor ");
            // Menyval för användaren att välja väg i programmet. Beroende på val skickas användaren till olika metoder som utreder specifika uppgifter. 

            Console.WriteLine("Meny: ");
            Console.WriteLine("Välj V för att tappetsera en vägg, M för att lägga mattor eller A för att avsluta programmet! ");
            Console.WriteLine("Tappetsera vägg (V)");
            Console.WriteLine("Lägga mattor (M)");
            Console.WriteLine("Avsluta programm (A)");
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n:");

            string val = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            //Anänver mig av en "switch" för att gå olika vägar beroende på användarens val i menyn. 
            switch (val)
            {
                //Tar in värdena bredd och längd och skickar in detta i metoden "tapeter".
                case "V":
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Vad är måtten på väggen du ska tappetsera? (Skriv i meter) ");
                        Console.WriteLine("Bredden: ");
                        double måttBredd = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine("Längden: ");
                        double måttLängd = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine($"Din area på väggen blir: {måttBredd * måttLängd}m^2 ");

                        Tapeter(måttBredd, måttLängd);
                        break;
                    }

                //Skickas direkt till metoden "mattor" som sedan returnar hur många mattor det krävdens
                case "M":
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Det krävdes {Mattor()} antal mattor för att täcka golvets yta! ");
                        break;
                    }
                case "A":
                    {
                        menyKörs = false;
                        break;
                    }

                //Avbryter koden genom att skickas till metoden "Felmeddelande"
                default:
                    {
                        Felmeddelande();
                        break;
                    }

            }

        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// En metod som berättar för användaren att ett felaktigt värde blivit angivet. Detta görs i en metod då vi minskar upprepning. 
    /// </summary>
    private static void Felmeddelande()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Du skrev in ett felaktigt värde, testa igen! ");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Räknar ut antal tapeter för en vägg och skriver ut dem
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="måttBredd">Den bredd väggen har</param>
    /// <param name="måttLängd">Den längd som väggen har</param>
    private static void Tapeter(double måttBredd, double måttLängd)
    {
        //Tapet
        //Olika lister där inmatning utav olika värden från användaren sparas för senare utskrivning
        List<int> listaTapet = new List<int>();
        List<string> listaNamn = new List<string>();
        List<double> listaPris = new List<double>();
        List<double> listaPrisTotal = new List<double>();


        int a = 0;
        bool tapetVäg = true;
        while (a <= 9 && tapetVäg)
        {
            //Menyval där användaren kan välja att lägga till en tapet för jämförelse, skriva ut tapeterna eller avsluta programmet. 
            Console.WriteLine("Vad vill du göra? Klicka 1, 2, respektive 3 för att välja: ");
            Console.WriteLine("Tänk på att du enbart kan jämföra !MAX! 8 st olika tapeter. ");
            Console.WriteLine("1: Lägga till en tapet");
            Console.WriteLine("2: Skriva ut listorna av tapeterna");
            Console.WriteLine("3: Avsluta programm");

            int valdVäg = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (valdVäg)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Vad heter din tapet? ");
                        string namnTapet = Console.ReadLine();
                        listaNamn.Add(namnTapet);

                        /*Räknar ut det antal rullar som användaren behöver. Detta görs utan hänsyn till mönster eller att tapeten ska sitta rätt.
                        Uträkningen görs genom att först dividera väggens bredd, (måttBredd), med tapetens bredd (tapetBredd), 
                        vilket ger oss antalet rullar vi behöver för att täcka väggens bredd med tapeter (antalRullar bredd). 
                        Detta värde avrundas uppåt då vi inte kan köpa halva tapetrullar. 
                        
                        Sedan multipliceras det antal tapeter som behövs för att täcka väggens bredd, (antalRullar bredd), med väggens längd, (måttLängd). Slutligen divideras detta med
                        tapetens längd, (tapetLängd), vilket ger oss totala antalet rullar vi behöver för att täcka hela väggen, (antalRullarVägg). 
                        Även detta värde, (antalRullarVägg), avrundas uppåt av samma anledning som innan. 
                        */

                        Console.WriteLine("Hur bred är tapeten? (meter) ");
                        double tapetBredd = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine("Hur lång är tapeten? (meter) ");
                        double tapetLängd = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        double antalRullarBredd = (måttBredd / tapetBredd);
                        int kolumnRullar = Convert.ToInt32((Math.Ceiling(antalRullarBredd)));
                        int antalRullarVägg = Convert.ToInt32((Math.Ceiling((antalRullarBredd * måttLängd) / tapetLängd)));
                        Console.WriteLine($"Totala antal rullar du behöver blir {antalRullarVägg} st");
                        listaTapet.Add(antalRullarVägg);

                        //Det totala priset blir antalet rullar tapet multiplicerat med vad en rulle tapet kostar. 
                        Console.WriteLine("vad kostar tapeten? (kr/rulle) ");
                        double tapetPris = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        double prisTotal = antalRullarVägg * tapetPris;
                        Console.WriteLine($"Det totala priset för din tapet blir därmet: {prisTotal} kr ");
                        listaPris.Add(tapetPris);
                        listaPrisTotal.Add(prisTotal);

                        Console.WriteLine("Tryck Enter för att fortsätta: ");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Clear();

                            break;
                    }

                case 2:
                    { 
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Här kommer dina tapeter som en lista: ");

                        //Räknar upp listorna i ordning med hjälp av en "foreach" där loopen körs tills det inte finns något mer i listan "listaNamn".
                        //Då listan "listaNamn" och alla andra listor är lika stora så kommer loopen skriva ut allt i listorna. 
                        for (int i = 0; i < listaNamn.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write("Namn: ");
                            Console.WriteLine(listaNamn[i]);
                            Console.Write("Antal tapetrullar: ");
                            Console.WriteLine(listaTapet[i]);
                            Console.Write("Kr/Rulle: ");
                            Console.WriteLine(listaPris[i]);
                            Console.Write("Totalt pris för tapet: ");
                            Console.WriteLine(listaPrisTotal[i]);
                            Console.Write("");
                        }

                            break;
                    }

                case 3:
                    {
                        tapetVäg = false;
                            break;
                    }
                        
                default:
                    {
                        Felmeddelande();
                            break;
                    }
            }

            a++;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Metod som körs för att täcka golvet med mattor
    /// </summary>
    static int Mattor()
    {
        //Skapar två lister för mattornas längd och bredd. Detta för att jag sedan ska kunna skriva ut mattorna som användaren har använt. 
        List<int> listaMattaBredd = new List<int>();
        List<int> listaMattaLängd = new List<int>();
        int b = 0;
        bool mattaVäg = true;
        while (mattaVäg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Meny: ");
            Console.WriteLine("1: Lägga till mattor");
            Console.WriteLine("2: Skriva ut mattorna");
            Console.WriteLine("3: Avsluta programm");
            int mattaVal = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (mattaVal)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Du ska täcka ditt golv med golvmattor. Jag behöver följande: ");
                        Console.WriteLine("Golvets bredd: ");
                        double golvBredd = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine("Golvets längd: ");
                        double golvLängd = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine($"Din area blir: {golvBredd * golvLängd} m^2 ");
                        double golvArea = golvLängd * golvBredd;

                        // "täcktGolv" sätts till noll och adderas varje gång anvädnaren valt att lägga till en matta på golvet. 
                        double täcktGolv = 0;
                        //Använder do-while för att se om mattorna tänker golvarean. Använder även en variabel som räknas efter varje gång loopen utförs för att bestämma antal mattor man behöver. 
                        
                        do
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Ta en matta och mata in mattans mått: ");
                            Console.WriteLine("Matta bredd: ");
                            int mattaBredd = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            listaMattaBredd.Add(mattaBredd);
                            Console.WriteLine("Matta längd: ");
                            int mattaLängd = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            listaMattaLängd.Add(mattaLängd);

                            täcktGolv = täcktGolv + (mattaBredd * mattaLängd);

                            Console.WriteLine($"Täckt golv blir: {täcktGolv} m^2");
                            b++;
                        } while (täcktGolv < golvArea);
                        return b;
                        
                    }

                case 2:
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Här kommer dina tapeter som en lista: ");

                        //Räknar upp listorna i ordning med hjälp av en "foreach" där loopen körs tills det inte finns något mer i listan "listaMattaBredd". 
                        //Då listan "listaMattaBredd" är lika stor som listan "listaMattaLängd" så kommer loopen skriva ut allt i listorna. 
                        for (int i = 0; i < listaMattaBredd.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write("Matta Bredd: ");
                            Console.WriteLine(listaMattaBredd[i]);
                            Console.Write("Matta Längd: ");
                            Console.WriteLine(listaMattaLängd[i]);
                            Console.Write("");
                        }
                        return b;
                        
                    }

                case 3:
                    {
                        mattaVäg = false;
                        return b;
                        
                    }


                default:
                    {
                        Felmeddelande();
                        return b;
                        
                    }
                    
            }

            

        }   
    }
}
```

Hi! I need some help to solve my problem. I don't know why I can't return my value b to my main method. I've written everything in Swedish so if you need some translation I will do that!

Thanks!

Comment: `Not all code paths return a value` means you have a path, that does not return a value, through a function whose declaration includes a return type. Specifically, `static int Mattor()` promises that it will return an `int`, but if `mattaVäg` is set to `false` before a `return` statement is encountered, control will fall out of the `while` loop and there will be no value to return. You should add a `return` statement after the `while` loop (or an `Exception` if that's more appropriate).

Comment: What does the compiler report? On which line(s) do you get the warnings? Just looking at those locations and following the flow of data is help full in answering your question (or for you so see where things go wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because all of your `returns` are in the while loop.
From msdn: [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements)

- The while statement: conditionally executes its body ***zero*** or more times.

Meaning that is not guaranteed that the code inside the `while` loop will be executed at all. It might just skip the whole, but no `returns` after it, that's why you are getting an error: `"Not all code paths return a value"`, although multiple paths `returns` a value, **NOT** all path.

You specified that the `mattaVag` variable is `true` at the beginning but the compiler doesn't know it. If this loop will be executed at least one time anyway, change it to `do...while`.
Or place the `return b;` outside your loop

```
static int Mattor() {
    int b = 0;
    bool mattaVäg = true;
    
    do {
        int mattaVal = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (mattaVal) {
            case 1:
                mattaVäg = false;
                break;
            case 2:
                mattaVäg = false;
                break;
            case 3:
                mattaVäg = false;
                break;
            default:
                Felmeddelande();
            break;
        }
    } while (mattaVäg);

    return b;
}
```

**Edit**: *"why can't i choose when i want to return a value and when not to?"*
You can choose. You choosed to return an `int`, so it must return an `int`.

You can try this:

Calling the method: `Mattor(out int b);`

```
//Note!!! This is now a void method. 
//No return value, but we passed in a variable what you will get back
static void Mattor(out int b) {
    b = 0;
    bool mattaVag = true;

    do {
        int mattaVal = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (mattaVal) {
            case 1: 
                b++;
                mattaVag = false;
                break;
            case 2:
                mattaVag = false;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    } while (mattaVag);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your respond, very kind of you! I've now tried your solution but it doesn't seem to work and the problem still stands. As I wrote in the comment above, i only really need to return the value b in case 1, because the value b counts how many times the user have done the "do while" loop.

Comment: Can you please paste your modified code up there?

Comment: I've made it work now thanks you to and the other guy! Thank you so much :) I looked at your code wrong firstly, but now I saw that you put the return b; outside the "Do-While", and now it works. But why does it work that way, and why can't i choose when i want to return a value and when not to?

Comment: You choosed to return a value when you created your method. static **int** Mattor(), if you don't want to return change it to void. Or... I show you someting else. 1 minute and write you an other piece of code.

Comment: Can I thank you in some way for you help? Maybe vote you up or something? I've just recently started to use this site. :)

Comment: @IsacEklindPettersson, yes. a vote up is good. Thank you for accepting my answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Move the statment `return b;` after the completion of outer while loop. When you are finish computing in each switch case, make sure to add break at the end. This will always return b whether it is 0 (default) or changed within the while loop.

```
static int Mattor()
{
  ...
  while (mattaVäg) {
    switch(mattaVal) {
      case 1: 
        // do work
        break;     <==== here

      default:
        // default work
        break;     <==== here
    }
  }
  return b;    <=== here
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment. I don't think I understand what you're doing. My problem is that I want to return my value b. which is how many times I've done the "do while" loop in case 1. I don't really need to return a value for any other case. Do you get what i mean?

Comment: I do ... when you have a method that must return value, you can't pick and chose which case will return value and which will not. When you move the return statement to end, you ensure a value is returned, whether default or calculated from a specific case

Comment: Okey, now I've got it! Thank you so much! So I can't pick and choose which case will return the value, and which will not. Why is that?